How to Create a Cascading Text Function
I'm working on a PHP function called cascade that accepts a string and an integer representing the gap between words. The function should return the text arranged in a cascading representation.
For example, if the function is called like this:
cascade("The codings bug", 2);

t should return:
T__c__b___
_h__o__u__
__e__d__g_
______i___
_______n__
________g_
_________s

Another example:
cascade("The coding bug", 3);

Should return:
T___c___b__
_h___o___u_
__e___d___g
_______i___
________n__
_________g_

Here is the current code I have written
function cascade(string $s, int $gap): string {
    $lines = [];
    $words = explode(' ', $s);
    
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $line = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
            $line .= str_repeat('_', $gap * $i) . $word[$i] . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $lines[] = trim($line); // Remove the trailing newline character
    }
    
    return implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
}

When I ran cascade('The codings bug', 2), I got the following result:
T __h ____e c __o ____d ______i ________n __________g ____________s b __u ____g


Here's an online version showing what the result looks like for reference: https://3v4l.org/Q5k3X

I would assume part of your algorithm needs to first determine the longest word, and you would need to loop from 1 to that length somewhere. Inside of that loop I think you take the nth letter from each word, or a blank if there are no letters. Something like that.

There are no bugs in your implementation, the issue is that it solves different problem, so you cannot "fix" it, you need to rethink algorithm and rewrite it.
There are multiple ways of doing it, but basically it boils down to calculating size of final matrix and then putting symbols of each word into correct positions, here is my take on it, it is not optimal, but can be used as starting point:
function cascade(string $s, int $gap): string {
    $words = explode(' ', $s);
    
    $maxHeight = 0;
    $maxWidth = 0;
    foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
        $wLen = strlen($word);
        $maxHeight = max($maxHeight, $wLen);
        $maxWidth = max($maxWidth, $wLen + $wi * ($gap+1));
    }
    
    $r = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$maxHeight; $i++) {
        $line = '';
        foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
            if ($i < strlen($word)) {
                $sp = $i + ($wi * ($gap + 1));
                while (strlen($line) < $sp) $line .= '_';
                $line .= $word[$i];
            }
        }
        while (strlen($line) < $maxWidth) $line .= '_';
        $r .= $line . "\n";
    }
    return $r;
}


The current calculation for $maxWidth does not consider the lengths of previous words and gaps, so it needs to sum up the lengths of the previous words and the spaces between them for the correct maximum width.

@ŁukaszD.Tulikowski why do you think so? it calculates X position of last symbol or each word and calculates maximum, so it considers all words

My bad. I realized that your calculation for $maxWidth already implicitly considers the lengths of previous words and gaps by multiplying the word's index by $gap + 1, effectively accounting for the gaps created by all preceding words.
